# Sub-Classing NSTextStorage Causes Significant Memory Issues

Tags: swift, uitextview, textkit, nstextstorage

I have a custom `UITextView` that takes advantage of Apple's TextKit by defining a custom `NSTextStorage` class, however, when I use my subclass for the custom text view's, text storage (as implemented below) and try opening any file greater than 20.0KB, the app crashes due to memory leakage: "`Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue`".

Oddly enough, if I replace my custom `BMTextStorage` with just a standard one, `NSTextStorage`, the text loads instantly without any memory leakage and uses < 30MB of RAM. What is causing this?

**TextView.swift**

```
class TextView : UITextView {

    required init(frame: CGRect) {

        // If I replace the following line with simply 
        // "let textStorage = NSTextStorage()"
        // I can open any file of any size and not have a memory leak
        // issue, using only about 20-30MB of RAM. If I ran this code
        // as is, it can open most files less than 20KB but will 
        // crash otherwise.
        let textStorage = BMTextStorage() 

        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()

        layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = true

        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSizeMake(.max, .max))

        textContainer.widthTracksTextView = true
        textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true
        textContainer.exclusionPaths = [UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, .max))]

        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)

        textStorage.delegate = self
        layoutManager.delegate = self

    }

}
```

**BMTextStorage.swift**

```
typealias PropertyList = [String : AnyObject]

class BMTextStorage : NSTextStorage {

    override var string: String {
        return storage.string
    }

    private var storage = NSMutableAttributedString()

    override func attributesAtIndex(location: Int, effectiveRange range: NSRangePointer) -> PropertyList {
        return storage.attributesAtIndex(location, effectiveRange: range)
    }

    override func replaceCharactersInRange(range: NSRange, withString str: String) {
        storage.replaceCharactersInRange(range, withString: str)
        edited([.EditedAttributes, .EditedCharacters], range: range, changeInLength: str.length - range.length)
    }

    override func setAttributes(attrs: PropertyList?, range: NSRange) {
        storage.setAttributes(attrs, range: range)
        edited([.EditedAttributes], range: range, changeInLength: 0)
    }

    override func processEditing() {
        super.processEditing()
    }

 }
```

Comment: Can you narrow it down to one of the four methods that you override? (And `processEditing()` can be removed altogether, as it doesn't do anything.)

Comment: @NRitH I can't narrow it down, easily as those methods are required by the abstract class to be overridden. And yes the problem doesn't change if I omit `processEditing()` I tried breakpoints I suppose, but it just loops forever before it crashes especially for large files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wow.... weird, it got fixed when I changed the type of `storage` to `NSTextStorage`....

```
typealias PropertyList = [String : AnyObject]

class BMTextStorage : NSTextStorage {

    overrride var string: String {
        return storage.string
    }

    private var storage = NSTextStorage()

    override func attributesAtIndex(location: Int, effectiveRange range: NSRangePointer) -> PropertyList {
        return storage.attributesAtIndex(location, effectiveRange: range)
    }

    override func replaceCharactersInRange(range: NSRange, withString str: String) {
        storage.replaceCharactersInRange(range, withString: str)
        edited([.EditedAttributes, .EditedCharacters], range: range, changeInLength: str.length - range.length)
    }

    override func setAttributes(attrs: PropertyList?, range: NSRange) {
        storage.setAttributes(attrs, range: range)
        edited([.EditedAttributes], range: range, changeInLength: 0)
    }

    override func processEditing() {
        super.processEditing()
    }

 }
```

Comment: Genius move! I wonder what freak cases this will break under, though. And do you now have to call `beginEditing`/`endEditing` for both `self` and `storage`?  But the memory problems are gone so far.

Comment: @ctietze oddly enough, I only make `beginEditing` and `endEditing` calls for `self` and it works out fine. I believe those methods are used primarily to help application manage the document state

Comment: I can't help but feel like this is a massive code smell from Apple's API... Also, why the /heck/ NSTextStorage is an "abstract" class when that makes no sense in Objective-C is another great indication that there is some black magic behind this powerful class. Thanks for the tip, though! +1

Comment: Awesome finding! like 4 years later

Comment: Thanks for the finding. I can't get them really smooth. It's still a bit flaky. I used `NSTextStorage()` and removed all beginEditing/endEditing from my overwritten implementation. Some ideas how to get awesome scroll experience?

Comment: Got it. Called `setApperance()` in a draw method. :facepalm: Thanks for the finding, even in 2021!